# Create a record automatically in another record when table gets a new record

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have two tables. I want to automatically create a record in the payment record with status `false` when a record has been added to `service` table. I would want the payment to look like this for e.g if service has been added

It should create a record in payment automatically like this:

```
id: autoincrement, fk_service 1, price null, payment_date null, status false
```

In my web app I will just update the values.

Original tables:

Service

```
id BIGSERIAL PK,
start_date date not null,
end_date date null,
status VARCHAR(20)
```

Payment

```
id BIGSERIAL PK,
fk_service BIGSERIAL,
price DECIMAL,
payment_date date,
status BOOLEAN not null,
FOREIGN KEY(fk_service) references service(id)
```

Can someone advice, how can I achieve this?

I tried writing a trigger

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION insert_payment() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $insert_payment$
BEGIN
    IF NEW service THEN
        insert into payment(fk_service, status) values (service.id, false) 
    END IF;
END;
```

I am getting `syntax error at or near create line 5 as $BODY$CREATE FUNCTION insert_payment() RETURNS TRIGGER^`

Comment: Take a look at [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: @JimJones can you advice what I am doing wrong with my trigger?

Comment: "*Create a record **in** a record*" makes no sense to me (ignoring the fact that tables have rows, not records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "attach" the function into at trigger, which will be listening events on the given table, e.g. an `AFTER INSERT` trigger

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_payment() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO payment(fk_service, status) values (NEW.id, false);
  RETURN NEW;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger on table `service`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER on_insert_service AFTER INSERT ON service
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_payment();
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a3f2da9d0a8be3dc15661b47d2e589bc)

Comment: Why do you add id into fk_serevice field?

Comment: If I recall it correctly (it's been over a year), it means that the id of the table service, which is a `serial`, will be inserted into the column `fk_service` of the table `payment` @S.W.G.